# Case Control Matching Closest Above/Below Rank with Replacements - How to Choose same observation several times

Tags: r, matching

I am wanting to create a new data set with the closest ranked "Other" Local Authorities to the "Glasgow" ones, both closest higher and lower. It is selection with replacement so the same observation can be chosen several times.

```
DataZone<- c("1005247", "1003253", "1003708", "1003158", "1003428", 
"1004568", "1008765", "1001122", "1005234")
LocalAuthority<-c("Other", "Glasgow","Glasgow","Glasgow","Glasgow", "Other", 
"Glasgow", "Glasgow", "Other")
Rank<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
df<-data.frame(DataZone, LocalAuthority, Rank)
```

What I want in the new data set is

DataZone 1005247  - 4 times as it's the closest lower to 4 of the Glasgow ones

DataZone 1004568 - 6 times as it's closest higher to 4 of the Glasgow ones and closest lower to 2 of the Glasgow DZs.

DataZone 1005234 - 2 times as it is the closest higher to 2 of the Glasgow ones

The code I have gives me a new data set with all the relevant DataZones, but it doesn't allow for Data Zones being picked several times:

```
 df<-df[order(df$Rank),]
 IncControls = Loop %>% 
 mutate(newcol = ifelse(!LocalAuthority=="Glasgow"&
 (lag(LocalAuthority)=="Glasgow"|lead(LocalAuthority)=="Glasgow"),1,0) ) %>% 
 filter(newcol==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the format of your output but you can try this

```
Lengths <- rle(LocalAuthority)$lengths
# 1 4 1 2 1
Positions <- cumsum(rle(LocalAuthority)$lengths)
# 1 5 6 8 9
isGlasgow <- rle(LocalAuthority)$values=="Glasgow"
# FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

F <- rep(DataZone[head(Positions[lead(isGlasgow)],-1)], Lengths[isGlasgow])
# "1005247" "1005247" "1005247" "1005247" "1004568" "1004568"
R <- rep(DataZone[tail(Positions[lag(isGlasgow)],-1)], Lengths[isGlasgow])
# "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1005234" "1005234"

ans <- sort(c(F,R))
ans
# "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1004568" "1005234"
# "1005234" "1005247" "1005247" "1005247" "1005247"

table(ans)
# 1004568 1005234 1005247 
#       6       2       4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not quite sure what format of output means (I'm quite new to this). What I am looking for is a list of DataZones so that I can merge it with the original data that has more variables and thereby create a data set with all variables for all the controls. 
Using this code I get a list of DataZones where when there are several non-Glasgow ones next to each other only the last one is counted and acts as the closest upper/lower ranked to the Glasgow ones even though there are other DataZones which should be counted instead.